# Custom Knockout binding failing when invoking default knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js

**Overview**

When creating a [knockout custom binding](http://jsfiddle.net/jamshall/6UtsP/1/) that contains a call to a knockout default binding, my custom binding stops working after the first call.

To see the issue, in the [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamshall/6UtsP/1/), change the selected item in the ddl once.  Text changes as expected.  Change it again, and nothing happens.  Fail.

**Details**

I am seeing some odd behavior when extending the default knockout binding "[html](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html)" with my own custom binding "htmlFade".  The behavior I am looking for is the same as the [html binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html), but with a JQuery fade animation to fade DOM elements in and out.

Code samples below.  A full JSFiddle example can be see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamshall/6UtsP/1/).

The HTML looks like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: names, value: selectedName"></select>  
<data-bind="htmlFade : selectedName" class="main"></div>
```

The Json Data looks like this:

```
var viewModel = {
    names: ko.observableArray(['Bob', 'Jon']),
    selectedName: ko.observable('Bob')
};
```

The Custom Binding looks like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.htmlFade = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.html.init();
        $(element).hide();
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).fadeOut(700, function() {
           ko.bindingHandlers.html.update(element, valueAccessor);           
           $(element).fadeIn(700);
        });        
    }
};
```

I am intentionally deferring to the default html handler with the line *"ko.bindingHandlers.html.update(element, valueAccessor)"*, because my goal is to *extend* the behavior, not recreate.

**The problem** I am having is that the above code works the first time select list is changed. After that it fails.

I created another [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamshall/kYwEE/1/) where instead of extending the behavior, I recreated it by adding the following line *"http://jsfiddle.net/jamshall/kYwEE/1/"* (copied from the [knockout source for the default html binding](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/html.js)) in place of the above referenced *html.update* call. This seems to work fine.

**My question**, then, is why does my Custom Binding stop working after the first call when I include a call to a default binding from withing it?  Or, to make it simple, why does [JSFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/jamshall/6UtsP/1/) not work but [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/jamshall/kYwEE/1/) work?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the `update` function of a custom binding like a computed observable (Knockout does use computed observables to track dependencies when the bindings on an element are executed).  So, in your custom binding you are not grabbing a dependency to the observable that you are bound against, because your code is being executed asynchronously.

In your `update`, you would probably want to do something like:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    //just grab dependency
    ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

    $(element).fadeOut(700, function() {
       ko.bindingHandlers.html.update(element, valueAccessor);           
       $(element).fadeIn(700);
    });        
}
```

So, we just access the value of the observable to grab a dependency.  `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` just safely handles retrieving the value no matter if it is a non-observable or observable.

Updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/6UtsP/10/